# How to translate a string, word by word, on FIFO basis in Perl given a string not an array?

Tags: regex, string, perl, translate

I have a string that is given (which means I can't store each token in an array in the beginning) in Perl:

```
$string = "applegrapeorangelimepineapple";
```

how do I match and 'shift' the first word from the string if it matches a list of words and print a related value?

I mean if apple is matched with the word "red", I need to first print the word "red", then remove the substring "apple" from the string $string, and the $string will then become:

```
$string = "grapeorangelimepineapple";
```

and continue to check for the first word again and if it matches a word in a master list of words "grape", the program will print "purple", and so on?

Overall, given a string:

```
$string = "applegrapeorangelimepineapple";
```

how to translate it into:

```
"red purple orange lime yellow";
```

and drop the irrelevant words or characters that are not found in the master list?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array of patterns that you wish to match, in the order you want to match them, then repeatedly pattern match against the beginning of your string. Note the below only attempts to match one pattern against the front of the string not all of them, it wasn't clear from your question which behavior you desired. Regardless, you should be able to adapt that solution from this one easily enough.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 

use strict; 
use warnings;

use feature qw(say);

my $string = "applegrapeorangelimepineapple";
my @patterns = qw(apple grape orange lime pineapple);
my %pattern_map; 
@pattern_map{@patterns} = qw(red purple orange yellow yellow);

foreach my $pattern ( @patterns ) {
   my ($match) = $string =~ s/^\Q$pattern\E//;
   next unless $match;

   say $pattern_map{$pattern};
}

__END__
red
purple
orange
yellow
yellow
```

Comment: Thanks Hunter McMillen. Do you also know how to escape the special symbol '^' ? I encounter this in my string as well.

Comment: @pythonhiew If you wrap the literal pattern you want to match in `\Q` and `\E` no regular expression metacharacters will be applied, they will just be treated as literal characters. You can see my edit for an example.

Comment: Can I use the $string =~ s/$string/\Q$variableFromMasterList\E/gi ? That way it will do the job for the whole string for me but then I think it's not working now. Sorry I didn't include in my question earlier because I just tried that.

Comment: You could do something like that if you wanted, but the `/g` flag matches across the whole string, so more than one match could be returned. You need to capture all of those matches, try `my @matches = $string =~ s/\Q$variableFromMasterList\E//gi;`

Comment: can't seem to work. maybe because the words are stuck together not separated by spaces. I don't know the way around it.

Comment: What is the value of your `$variableFromMasterList` variable?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75433/discussion-between-hunter-mcmillen-and-pythonhiew).